# Converting Matlab function 'get_angle' into Python

Tags: python, matlab, translate

I am converting a Matlab script into a Python script and I have come across the following function:

```matlab
function[angle]= get_angle(N,fs,d_micro)
    if N~=0,
       j=0.1;
       x=-20:j:20;
       [y1]=hiper(N,x,-d_micro/2,fs);
       x1=round(length(x)/4);x2=round(length(x)/8);
       pendiente=(y1(x1)-y1(x2))/(j*(x1-x2));


       if N>0
            angulorad=atan(pendiente);
            angulo1=angulorad*180/pi;
            angle=-90-angulo1;
       else
            angulorad = atan(-pendiente);
            angulo1 = angulorad*180/pi;
            angle = 90 - angulo1;
       end
    else
       angle=0;
    end
end
```

where `hiper` is another function.

The conversion I have done is as follows:

```py
def get_angle(N,fs,d_micro):
    if N != 0:
        j = 0.1
        x = np.arange(-20,20,j)
        y1 = hiper(N,x,-d_micro/2,fs)
        x1 = round(len(x))
        x2 = round(len(x)/8)
        pendiente = (y1(x1)-y1(x2))/(j*(x1-x2))
        if N>0:
            angulorad = np.arctan(pendiente)
            angulo1 = angulorad*180/np.pi
            angle = -90-angulo1
        else:
            angulorad = np.arctan(-pendiente)
            angulo1 = angulorad*180/np.pi
            angle = 90-angulo1
    else:
        angle = 0
    return angle
```

I am not sure that this is correct, but I haven't converted enough of the rest of the code to check it yet.

Is this conversion correct?

Comment: @Mous Is my conversion correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that the result of `-20:0.1:20` in Matlab is different from the result of `np.arange(-20, 20, 0.1)` in Python.